# SVG image shows up fine in chrome and ie but is distorted in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, svg, cross-browser

For some reason, my SVG image looks distorted while viewing it on FireFox. I'm not sure how to fix this. I saw someone post an answer to a similar problem which was

`<img srcset=".svg" src=".png"> <!--for browsers that don't support SVG'S-->`

but this didn't resolve my issue. Any help would be appreciated so I can spread the word if anyone else has this problem in the future. Thanks!

[image: This is what the image looks like in FireFox]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- Nav Bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-nav fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <img class= "logo"  src="https://res.cloudinary.com/alexscloud1234/image/upload/v1518821671/logo_xmc12c.svg" alt="logo" height="50px" width="240px"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- container -->
  </nav>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] derived from your svg image to the question. At the moment you've put everything except that image in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First Your SVG have the issue. 
(1) check with this online editor : http://editor.method.ac/ 
(2) open your file into chrome browser you will miss alignment for char "rch"

solution is generate svg again also group this char with : "Solutions for Research" combine into one group.